# Exact repeating alarm on Marshmallow without setAlarmClock()

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

In one app I get accelerator sensor value each 30 sec in the background. Since Android M introduced Doze mode, in Doze mode all alarm won't work exactly except `setAlarmClock()`. But if `setAlarmClock()` with short time will disable Doze and make user angry with alarm icon.

`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` is not the solution because it is 15 min exact.

I believe with Google Play service they can archive this in Fit API without `setAlarmClock()`, collect accelerator sensor value and count user step (offline).